# What does "modules" refer to in this Makefile?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Here is a sample Makefile which makes use of the keyword `modules` twice (apart from the ones that appear in the path and PHONY).

```
# Path to the kbuild Makefile of the kernel to compile against
export KERNEL_BUILD_PATH := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
# Name of this kernel module
export KERNEL_MODULE     := hello
# List of kernel headers to include (e.g.: "linux/netdevice.h")
export KERNEL_INCLUDE    := 
# Path to the directory where kernel build artifacts should be stored
export BUILD_DIRECTORY   := build
# List of C files to compile into this kernel module
export C_FILES           := $(wildcard src/*.c)
# List of all Rust files that will be compiled into this kernel module
export RUST_FILES        := $(wildcard src/*.rs)
# Base directory of the Rust compiler
export RUST_ROOT         := /usr

# Rust compiler settings
export CARGO      = $(RUST_ROOT)/bin/xargo
export CARGOFLAGS =
export RCFLAGS    =
export RELEASE    =

-include ./config.mk


# Top-level project directory
export BASE_DIR := $(patsubst %/,%,$(dir $(abspath $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)))))


# Prevent command echoing, unless the (Kbuild-style) `V=1` parameter is set
ifneq "$(V)" "1"
.SILENT:
endif


all modules: ${BUILD_DIRECTORY}/Makefile
    @$(MAKE) -C "${KERNEL_BUILD_PATH}" M="${BASE_DIR}/${BUILD_DIRECTORY}" modules
    cp "${BUILD_DIRECTORY}/${KERNEL_MODULE}.ko" "${KERNEL_MODULE}.ko"

# Make sure there always is a target `Makefile` for kbuild in place
${BUILD_DIRECTORY}/Makefile: kbuild.mk
    @mkdir -p "${BUILD_DIRECTORY}/src"
    cp "kbuild.mk" "${BUILD_DIRECTORY}/Makefile"

insmod:
    sudo insmod "${KERNEL_MODULE}.ko"
    dmesg | tail

rmmod:
    sudo rmmod "${KERNEL_MODULE}"
    dmesg | tail

clean:
    rm -rf "${BUILD_DIRECTORY}"
    $(CARGO) clean

test: ${KERNEL_MODULE}.ko
    sudo insmod "${KERNEL_MODULE}.ko"
    sudo rmmod  "${KERNEL_MODULE}"
    dmesg | tail -3

.PHONY: all modules clean insmod rmmod test
```

My questions are:

- In line 35, does `all modules` refer to two separate targets e.g. `all` and `modules` together? If so, why do we name the same rule with two different names? Doesn't the rule become recursive?
- In line 36, what is the significance of the keyword `module` appearing at the end?
- In line 36, what does `M=` stand for?

Answer (score 0):

```
all modules
```

is quite unfortunate name of the target. It will be called each time Makefile is "executed" without any target specified. It will be also called when you call `make -f Makefile modules`. I wouldn't call a target that way.

```
all modules:
    @echo "Hello"

.PHONY: all modules
```

if you run this one

```
> make
Hello
```

As for **M=**

```
value:
    @echo $(M)
```

M= simply passes variable that will be visible inside Makefile

```
> make M=hohoho -f Makefile value
hohoho
```

Comment: `all modules` is not the name of a target.  It means that two completely different targets are defined, `all` and `modules`, and they both have the same recipe.  So if you run `make all` or `make modules` it will run this same recipe.  It's exactly the same as writing the entire rule twice, once with a target `all` and once with a target `modules`.  Except, less typing.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I wrote "unfortunate name of the target" in a sense that it would be more clear to do "all: modules" and then create target modules. But you are right. It is not a single target, but two separate.